# Need to join two lists (date and time) into one list

Tags: python

I have two lists:

`date = ['09.10.2019', '09.10.2019', '09.10.2019']`

and

`time = ['8:00', '9:00', '10:00']`

and I need to create a new one that should look like:

`date_time = ['09.10.2019 8:00', '09.10.2019 9:00', '09.10.2019 10:00']`

I've already tried to use .append():

````
```date_time=[]
for element in data:
    date_time.append(date+time)```
````

, but I'm not able to add a space between them:

`date_time = ['09/10/201901:00', '09/10/201902:00', '09/10/201903:00']`

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to add the space yourself, or use string formatting. E.g. `date_time = [f"{d} {t}" for d, t in zip(date, time)]`, which uses formatted strings (requires Python 3.6 or newer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` and `zip` together with `' '.join`:

```
map(' '.join, zip(date, time))
```

Comment: you may want to note that this will return map object and need to be converted to list, otherwise OP may wonder what to do with map object